# Image masking is not working properly, the output image is black-and-white, it should be colourful

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to do image masking here is my output and code.

This is my masking reference image(Image size doesn't matter),

**mask.png,**

[image: Masking Image]

This is image on which i'm performing masking,

**imggo.png,**

[image: Image on which masking is performed (Here the image size doesn't matter)]

This is the **Output**.

[image: Output]

I'm using **Swift**, Here is my code...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var maskRefImg : UIImage? = UIImage(named: "mask.png")
    var maskImg :UIImage? = UIImage(named: "imggo.png")

    var imgView: UIImageView? = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 50, 99, 99))
    imgView?.image = maskImage(maskRefImg!, maskImage: maskImg!)


self.view.addSubview(imgView!)
}


func maskImage(image:UIImage,maskImage:UIImage)-> UIImage{

    var maskRef:CGImageRef = maskImage.CGImage

    var mask:CGImageRef = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef), CGImageGetHeight(maskRef), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef), CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef), CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), nil, true)

    var masked:CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMask(image.CGImage, mask)


return UIImage(CGImage: masked)!

}
```

**So,How can I make Go! image colourful.?**
**Would anyone provide code.?**

Comment: Looking at the variable names `img` and `maskimg` and the images you're loading there, haven't you actually _swapped_ them? I mean, `maskimg` should load `mask.png`, right?

Comment: Updated confusing variable names, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function `maskImage` with the wrong order of arguments:

The `maskImage` function wants the image to mask first, and then the mask. But when you call `maskImage(maskRefImg!, maskImage: maskImg!)` you have it exactly swapped.

So you need to call `maskImage(maskImg!, maskImage: maskRefImg!)`

---

I'm guessing that what you want to have is the tilted rectangle with the word "Go!" and that the result image should be exactly the same size as the mask image.

When you swap the images (as you must), the mask image is scaled to the "Go!" image size. But instead, you probably want the mask image centered over your "Go!" image. So you need to [create a new image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreate) with the same size as your "Go!" image and draw the mask centered into that temporary image. You then use the temporary image as the actual mask to apply.

The example image when you swap the arguments also shows that the "outside" is also green. This probably because your mask image is transparent there and `CGImageMaskCreate` converts it to black. But the [documentation of `CGImageCreateWithMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithMask) basically tells you that the created image will blend the "Go!" image so that parts where your mask image is black will have the "Go!" image visible and where your mask image is white it will be transparent.

The step-by-step instructions thus are:

- Create a new, temporary image that is of the same size as your input image (the "Go!" image).
- Fill it with white.
- Draw your mask image centered into the temporary image.
- Create the actual mask by calling `CGImageMaskCreate` with the temporary image.
- Call `CGImageCreateWithMask` with the "Go!" image as first argument and the actual mask we've just created as second argument.
- The result might be too big (have a lot of transparency surrounding it). If you don't want that you need to crop the result image (e.g. to the size of your original mask image; make sure to crop to the *center*).

You can probably skip the `CGImageCreateWithMask` part if you immediately create the temporary image in the DeviceGray color space, as `CGImageCreateWithMask` wants the second argument to be an image in this color space. In that case, I suggest you modify your `mask.png` so it does not contain any transparency: it should be white where it's transparent now.

Comment: Yes,But when i swap that order, it doesn't give desired output.
Instead it just make white frame of mask.png on imggo.png.

Comment: Please be more specific: how does the output look like? When you look at the [documentation for `CGImageCreateWithMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithMask) your current call is wrong. You do need to swap it (in other words, the first argument to `CGCreateImageWithMask` must be the `imggo.png` image).

Comment: This is the output when I swap them,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/do5a0x5rvhysojg/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2006-Jan-2015%207.36.02%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: Could you please provide Any code?
It will be appreciated.

Comment: Oh come on, you can do it! Believe in yourself ;-)